# How to install Flask on Python3 using pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

I want to try using Flask with Python3. I've got Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, which supposedly ships with pip included. So I tried

```
pip3 install flask
```

this ends in:

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_kramer65/flask/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-i98xjzea-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_kramer65/flask
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpqc3b2nu5
```

So I tried importing it, but to no avail:

```
kramer65@vps1:~/cxs$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

I can of course download it and install using `sudo python3 setup.py install` it that way, but I would rather do it "the standard way" so that things are easily and more standard to setup on production machines.

Does anybody know how I can import Flask with Python3 and pip? All tips are welcome!

Error log is available in http://pastebin.com/hd6LyVFP

Comment: Post the contents of `/tmp/tmpqc3b2nu5` please.

Comment: @msvalkon - There was quite a lot of content, so I pasted it in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/hd6LyVFP   Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You seem to have a permission issue. From the log you pasted to pastebin:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask': Permission denied
```

This is because `pip` will attempt to install the package globally unless you specify a certain installation location. If you want to install this globally you must use `sudo` or install as a user with privileges.

Try the following:

```
sudo pip3 install flask
```

Or specify to a certain dir:

```
pip install -t <path> flask
```

However, with the latter method you will have to always inject the path to `sys.modules` so I suggest you just use `sudo` if you can.

Or even more preferrably, use [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Virtualenv allows you to *very easily*  package your application for production because you can install only the packages you need and you've thus got automatic package isolation. Generating a `requirements.txt` is then as simple as `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Remeber that if you end using a virtualenv, you *must not* use `sudo` to install packages as they will then be installed outside the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.6.4 version, it is possible to install Flask by doing:

```
sudo pip3.6 install flask
```